# Error when deleting and printing a line with a loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

When I make a for loop for a line in a text file and print the line then remove it. It removes the consecutive line not the line I printed. I want it to print the line then delete it. I need this to finally complete my brute force script.

```
file = input("Enter the list:")

with open(file) as f:
    file = list(f)

while True:
   for line in file:
     try:
         print(line)
         file.remove(line)
     except:
         print("of course")
```

Comment: Why are you trying to open a string as a file?

Comment: Are you trying to delete lines from the file on disk, or from the list in memory? Originally `file` is the name of a file on disk, but later it is a list of rows from that file, with no connection to the original file (i.e. deleting from this list won’t affect the file on disk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `file = list(f)` where the usual idiom would be to assign `f.readlines()`,
but that's fine.

Then you mutate a list while iterating over it.
That's a little more of a problem.
Also, using `pop(0)` would be more natural than asking [`remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to
search for a value matching `line` (which should be the first value encountered).

Here is a simpler example of mutating while iterating:

```
>>> lst = [4, 5, 6]
>>> for item in lst:
...   print(lst.pop(0))
... 
4
5
```

Popping within the loop interferes with the iteration, which is expected because
we shouldn't have been mutating during iteration in the first place.
The `item` variable never takes on the value `5`.

Making a copy and iterating over *that* is one way out:

```
>>> lst = [4, 5, 6]
>>> for item in list(lst):
...   print(lst.pop(0))
... 
4
5
6
```

Perhaps you don't want to make a copy of the list.
This code looks more like Fortran than Python,
but the behavior it shows is probably closer to what you were hoping for.

```
>>> lst = [4, 5, 6]
>>> for i in range(len(lst)):
...   print(i, lst.pop(0))
... 
0 4
1 5
2 6
```